# Unable to use option key in some Xcode keyboard shortcuts

Tags: xcode

What I really like with a text editor (or IDE) is to be able to easily remap its keyboard shortcuts to what I want, and Xcode seems to do a bad job with this.

I want to be able to switch file tabs by using `option + command + arrow` (left and right arrows). However, when I try to change keyboard shortcuts for the `Show Previous Tab` and `Show Next Tab` actions, the `option` key is not applied.

[image: Xcode showing the wrong shortcut]

In the screenshot, you can see—through [KeyCastr](https://github.com/keycastr/keycastr)—how I pressed the `option + command + right arrow` keys and end up with `command + right arrow` in Xcode, the `option` key is missing.

Is there any solution? Note that the `option` key can be used on some actions, for example I can use it with the `About Xcode` action, but this is obviously not what I want.

I'm using Xcode 13.4.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so I've found a solution. Not a perfect one but it works!

There is no way to use the `option` key in some actions because they are constrained by the Navigation in Xcode preferences.

Instead you can change the system preferences to add a new shortcut to the Xcode app.

[image: System preferences showing keyboard shortcuts (with the option key) for Xcode]

However, when you will use those keyboard shortcuts in Xcode, you will see a weird behavior where the tab you are switching to, gets opened in a new editor.

This is due to the default navigation preferences of Xcode, change the "Optional Navigation" preference from "Uses Next Editor" to "Uses Tab".

[image: Xcode preferences showing the "Optional Navigation" preference being defined to "Uses Next Editor" by default]

Comment: This solved the problem!!! You are a hero. I honestly think Xcode's default behavior is very very weird. Until now, I still don't know what exactly is `Optional Navigation` even after reading this answer.

Comment: I will second your hero status. The "Uses Tab" hint was above and beyond :)